# Cron amavis - Wide character in print at Logger

Tags: ubuntu, cron

Amavis spams me very often with this e-mail sent to root:

Subject: `Cron <amavis@servername> test -e /usr/sbin/amavisd-new-cronjob && /usr/sbin/amavisd-new-cronjob sa-sync`

Body: `Wide character in print at /usr/share/perl5/Razor2/Logger.pm line 107.`

How is it possible to repair it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
Code is here...

## sudo vi /usr/share/perl5/Razor2/Logger.pm

```
00008:   use POSIX qw(strftime);
00009:   use IO::File;
00010:   # 2003/09/10 Anne Bennett: syslog of our choice (uses socket,
00011:   # does not assume network listener).
00012:   use Sys::Syslog;
00013: + use Encode;
00014:   
00015:   # designed to be inherited module
00016:   # but can stand alone.

00106:         my $fd = $self->{fd};
00107: -       print $fd "$now_string$logstr";
00107: +       print $fd encode('utf-8', "$now_string$logstr");
00108:     }
```